# Is there a python standard function to parse a string into an argv list exactly like bash does, in Python?

Tags: python, string-parsing

Consider the following string:

```
./kmux.py  -r 'messenger.* xx'
```

If `kmux.py` is a python script, and the string above was given to bash as an argument, then `sys.argv` will be the following list:

```
["./kmux.py", "-r", "messenger.* xx"]
```

**Is there a standard python function that will take the first string and turn it into the array?**

I could manually replicate bash's logic in Python to take the original string and turn it into this array, but I am curious about whether such a function already exists.

Comment: Does [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the default [`shlex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) package like so:

```
import shlex
shlex.split("'./kmux.py  -r 'messenger.* xx'")
```